# Custom Pricing for App

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, isv, pricing

After talking to an ISV rep at Salesforce they recommended that my application have pricing based on the # of seats/licenses but my application has a fundamentally different pricing structure. It's variable from month to month and based on usage rather than seats.

How should I handle the pricing in my appexchange app? The options are:

- This app is free and never requires any payment(obviously not this)
- This app is free but requires a paid subscription to an external service
- This app is initially free but payment is required for additional users, features or usage

I feel like #2 or #3 would work but want to make sure I don't paint myself into a corner.

The customers would work with me to determine the usage tier that they want to buy, we negotiate on price and they sign a contract, receive an invoice, etc.

Any guidance on this from folks who've been here would be great!

Comment: How are you going to determine usage? SF licensing model does not support usage based notifications nor feature set licenses. It either seat or site. Is your app connecting to an external service and usage is made there? If so make the app free but charge for access to the external service based on usage. Put your licensing there.

Comment: The external application handles all of the work, processing and updates in SFDC. SFDC is just the platform to interact with the data provided. So I manage all usage tracking on my end

Comment: You say " based on usage" where is the usage determined? If it is at the external service I would put all access, payment, licensing, etc there off the salesforce platform

Comment: I hit submit too quick and had to edit. It's managed in my application(separate from SFDC)